# My pc shut down automatically when I unplug the charger on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: power-management, asus, battery

I have Ubuntu 18.04 on an [Asus x541u](https://www.asus.com/us/search/results.aspx?SearchKey=x541U) with 8 GB of RAM, and the NVIDIA Geforce Gt920m graphics adapter.

Recently, the PC shuts down when I unplug the charger, even though the battery does not show as low or empty. Before in Windows, everything worked properly.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it *shut down cleanly*, carefully quitting all of your open applications and terminating processes in an organized way...or does it simply *poweroff instantly*, complaining and sometimes requiring a fsck at next reboot? Big difference.

Answer (score 0):

A laptop battery can look OK, but when you increase the current you draw from it, can suddenly drop its output voltage, resulting in the shutdown you mention.

Your best way to confirm that is to replace the battery, for battery testers which work on laptop batteries are few and far between.

BTW, Asus Support at https://www.asus.com/us/support/ has free chat agents who can help you verify this theory.

Comment: But I don't think it's hardware issue. When I was using windows. I didn't facing those issues. Perhaps it's a software issue. This issue started after I installed an update few days ago.

Comment: Then try booting from a LiveUSB from another distro other than 18.04; perhaps Lubuntu 19.10? https://lubuntu.me/downloads/